# How do I configure log4net when unit testing with MSpec?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, log4net, mspec

I am trying to retire my in-house logging utility in favour of something 'off the peg', specifically log4net. I have it all working, except that I can't get it to work when I'm running my tests (specifications) in the ReSharper test runner.

I'm using MSpec (Machine.Specifications) as my test framework. If I understand things correctly, I get an assembly-level setup by implementing the `IAssemblyContext` interface. So, here's my assembly setup:

```
public class AssemblySetup : IAssemblyContext
    {
    public void OnAssemblyStart()
        {
        Trace.WriteLine("In assembly setup");
        var fullPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "log4net4mspec.config");
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fullPath);
        XmlConfigurator.Configure(fileInfo);
        var log = LogManager.GetLogger("Assembly Setup");
        log.Info("Logging configured");
        }

    public void OnAssemblyComplete() {}
    }
```

I put the Trace.WriteLine() in there to verify that the code executes, and guess what? It doesn't! In the test results, nothing comes out:
[image: Test results]

The line that comes out from TiGra.Diagnostics is my 'old faithful' logging utility, which I am trying to retire. Not a squeak from log4net, or from that trace statement in my assembly setup. If I set a breakpoint on it and debug the tests, then the breakpoint isn't hit either, all of which indicates that the assembly setup isn't running.

Am I doing it wrong, or is something fishy going on here?

### UPDATE

Using the console runner, and watching the trace output with DebugView, I get this coming out:

```
[11704] In assembly setup 
[11704] Assembly Setup: INFO - Logging configured 
[11704] Initializing logging 
[11704] Assembly Setup: INFO - Logging configured by with_log4net 
[11704] TA.[TopSecret].Serial.SerialChannel: INFO - Starting transaction, timeout=00:00:02 txMsg=:MS# 
[11704] ===== TiGra.Diagnostics Initialized: Default TraceLevel = Verbose =====
```

So that looks like it is working and the assembly setup is working in the console runner. This is enough to make me doubt myself slightly, but "my" diagnostics has always worked for me in this situation so I'm not sure what's going on. Should I use the ConsoleAppender with MSpec instead of the Trace appender?

Comment: You're running the `Configure` method, that's good. I would rig up a super simple console logger and turn [log4net debug mode](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug) on and give us that output. Also, does `Trace` usually print in whatever console you're showing there? I've used `Console` and `Debug` print methods before with ReSharper.

Comment: "my" diagnostics (the Tigra.Diagnostics... line) is coming out OK, I use Trace.WriteLine() to produce that, so the Trace.WriteLine() that I put in the assembly setup should be coming out too, but it isn't. This suggests to me that the code isn't running at all and its not a log4net issue.

Comment: Anthony - which appender is the best to use with MSpec in ReSharper? I've always used Trace.WriteLine so I assumed the TraceAppender would be the way to go - should I prefer a different appender?

Comment: I don't really understand the Windows tracing system. I've always written to the ReSharper console using `Console.WriteLine(string)`. I don't trust trace or debug to _always_ output there.

Comment: For _testing_ logging code, which is occasionally a good idea, configure a [`MemoryAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.MemoryAppender.html) and you can assert on it's public properties. Here are [some examples](https://github.com/AnthonyMastrean/log4net-pro/search?q=memoryappender&ref=cmdform) of testing log4net with a memory appender.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, I remember adding this specifically to one of the ReSharper runners of the 0.5.x era.

I guess you have tested with the console runner as well?

What log4net appenders are configured?

Comment: No, I haven't tested with the console running, I will do that today and let you know. I'm using the TraceAppender.